# Using pool.map to run multiple functions in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to run in parallel multiple functions. I tried this

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def smap(f, *args):
    return f(*args)

def somma(*args):
    a=args[0]
    b=args[1]
    return a+b

def prodotto(*args):
    a=args[0]
    b=args[1]
    return a*b

pool = Pool(processes=2)
a=2
b=4
res=pool.map(smap, [(somma,a,b),(prodotto,a,b)])
print(res)
```

with the following error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the entire tuple as the first argument `f` to function `smap`, which is not a function as you intended. You can change `smap` to:

```py
def smap(f_args):
    f, *args = f_args
    return f(*args)
```

This will correctly accept only one argument from `Pool.map` and split `f` and `args` inside the call.

Answer (score 3):

You are expecting the `pool.map` internals to do the unpacking in `smap` for you but this is something which the logic cannot handle. You need to explicitely do it yourself.

```
def smap(params): 
    function, *args = params 

    return function(*args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `starmap` because `map` supports only one iterable argument
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap